# $\mathrm{Hom}(R/I, R/J\otimes M)\cong ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring, $I,J$ two ideal of $R$ and $M$ an $R-$module. Does anyone see the isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(R/I, R/J\otimes M)\cong \ldots$?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I,N)\simeq (0:_NI)$, where $(0:_NI)=\{x\in N:Ix=0\}$. Since $R/J\otimes M\simeq M/JM$ one can take $N=M/JM$ and get $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, R/J\otimes M)\simeq(JM:_MI)/JM$.